# Setting system property to a file path

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to set `System.setProperty` to a file path:

```
//properties key
String propFile = "propertiesFile";
String pathToFile = "properties/prop.properties";
File file = new file(pathToFile);
//properties value
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.setProperty(propFile, path);
//using properties.....
```

And I am getting `FileNotFoundException`.
when printing the file I get the `absolutePath`  - `c:\Project...\prop.properties`
Is setting `System.setProperty` should be done another way?
the `properties` - package inside `src`.

Comment: "properties/prop.properties" is not a correct path to use in File constructor method....

Comment: OK, what is the correct way?

Comment: you should use getClass().getResourceAsStream(""); to access to a file in package in a jar... and then you can write it in a file on HDD and set it`s path to System Property

Comment: Thanks, but I want only the file path... not InputStream, there isnt getPath method on InputStream....

Comment: use Files.copy(InputStream, targetfile.getPath() ,CopyOptions); to write input Stream in a file on HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the method `System.setProperty` as your path is managed as any other `String`, your problem is more that `new File(pathToFile)` refers to a non existing file as you provide a relative path and the absolute path is created from the user directory (value of `System.getProperty("user.dir")`) which is probably not what you expect. If you call `new File(pathToFile).exists()` it will return `false` check the resulting path first.